# Загрузка файлов через контроллер

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet, redirect, fileupload

Есть контроллер через который проходят все входящие запросы на сервер. Есть сервлет для загрузки файлов. Пробую напрямую на сервелет загрузки файлов делать обращение - загружает, а если через контроллер то нет.

В контроллере делаю перенаправление на нужный сервлет

```
rd = context.getRequestDispatcher("/UploadFile");
                    rd.forward(request, response);
```

но параметр `request.getPart("file");` получается `null`.

почему? как исправить?

Контроллер:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String[] path = request.getPathInfo().replaceFirst("^/+", "").split("/+");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(path));

        ServletContext context= getServletContext();

        RequestDispatcher rd = null;

        String action = "";

        for(int i=1;i<path.length;i++) {
            action+="/"+path[i];
        }
        if(session.getAttribute("token") != null && session.getAttribute("token").equals(Sloyev.GetCookieValue("token", request))) {
            request.setAttribute("action", action);
            switch (path[0]){
                case Sloyev.CONTROLLER_USER:
                    rd = context.getRequestDispatcher("/UserController");
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                    break;
                case Sloyev.CONTROLLER_ADMIN:
                    rd = context.getRequestDispatcher("/AdminController");
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                    break;
                case Sloyev.CONTROLLER_UTILS:
                    rd = context.getRequestDispatcher("/UtilsController");
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                    break;
                case Sloyev.CONTROLLER_UPLOAD:
                    rd = context.getRequestDispatcher("/UploadFile");
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                    break;
                default:
                    result.put(Sloyev.TYPE_STATUS, Sloyev.TYPE_ERROR);
                    result.put(Sloyev.TYPE_MESSAGE, "Controller - Unknown action.");
                    out.write(result.toJSONString());
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            result.put(Sloyev.TYPE_STATUS, Sloyev.TYPE_ERROR);
            result.put(Sloyev.TYPE_MESSAGE, "Bad token");
            out.write(result.toJSONString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: А до форварда `request.getPart("file")` точно возвращает не null?

Comment: @GreyGoblin я же говорю что пробовал напрямую - сразу на сервлет загрузки и всё работает - сохраняет файл.

Comment: Я это прочитал. Отсюда и вопрос возник. Если при прямом обращению к сервлету который замэплен на `UploadFile` у вас нет проблем с получением данных в `request.getPart("file")`, а через контроллер эти проблемы есть, то возникает подозрение, что где то в процессе этот `request` модифицируется. Может не в самом коде контроллера, а в каком-либо слушателе.

Comment: покажите код контроллера

Comment: @BogdanK добавил в шапку.

Comment: @GreyGoblin не использую слушатели. код контроллера в шапку добавил.

Comment: @Tsyklop, это не совсем контроллер. Контроллер принимает запросы а не посылает..

Comment: @BogdanK так это `doPost` моего контроллера (JavaEE). сервелета на которую приходят все запросы от клиента.